# Not able to display a dataframe in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-synapse

The  display function is not working on PySpark dataframes, but the show function works. I needed the interactive chart that Synapse renders.

The display function is returning

DataFrame[a: string, b: array, b: array, d: array, e: array, f: array, g: array]

In the same notebook it is the same case with other data frames.

Comment: I have tried out different browsers, deleting the cookies and in private windows

Comment: I scaled the nodes of the spark poll and it worked sometime ago. But now again increasing the nodes is not working

Comment: Is this only for a spark dataframe or do you have the same thing with a pandas one as well?